# Adding admob underneath game view

Tags: java, android, admob, libgdx

I have been trying to put admob underneath my game view.

here is my code

```
public class HoodStarGame extends AndroidApplication {
@Override public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Create the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new HoodStar(), false);

    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    AdRequest request = new AdRequest();
    request.addTestDevice(AdRequest.TEST_EMULATOR);
    request.addTestDevice("7ADDEC88A42947CD1FD7F2EC2F527485");

    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "a14f19c2fe8d9e0"); // Put in your secret key here
    adView.loadAd(request);

    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView);

    // Add the AdMob view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

}

However when run this the ads show on top of the game screen at the bottom

how can i sort this out?

Comment: A screenshot would help clarify the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing true
adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);

most likely you will want to set a margin for the gameLayoutParams:

gameLayoutParams.bottomMargin = 55;// whatever the height is

Comment: Maybe i was unclear, i didn't mean underneath as in behind, i meant below