# How can i place admob ads above a LibGDX view

Tags: java, android, android-layout, admob, libgdx

I've read many tutorials such as this one:

https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Admob-in-libgdx

however I cant seem to get my head round one thing. They all use ads which overlap the game view and I would rather it went above, and my game view was just squished down. How can i go about doing this? I have tried using Linear Layout but that doesn't seem to work either

this is my onCreate() method

```
@Override public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create the layout
        RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

        // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

        // Create the libgdx View
        View gameView = initializeForView(new HelloWorld(), false);

        // Create and setup the AdMob view
        AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxx"); // Put in your secret key here
        adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

        // Add the libgdx view
        layout.addView(gameView);

        // Add the AdMob view
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

        layout.addView(adView, adParams);

        // Hook it all up
        setContentView(layout);
    }
```

Comment: Check it out in the given link. It uses relative layout.

[Admob in LibGdx][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985828/how-to-implement-admob-in-my-game-in-libgdx/17986528#17986528

Comment: @KumarSaurabh this is my problem, it overlaps! this doesnt solve anything, though i appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165263/adding-admob-underneath-game-view), you can set a margin to your gameview, which works pretty well:

```
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameViewParams =
            new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    gameViewParams.bottomMargin = 150;

    View gameView = initializeForView(new MainGame(), cfg);
    layout.addView(gameView, gameViewParams);

    AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("app-id");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    setContentView(layout);
```

Using this, the adView is below the gameview, but I guess you can put a `marginTop` and have your gameview below the adView.

Comment: Is it another solution for this either than using hard-coded value for the margin? Since I have similar problem, but the banner height is variable, since I use the SMART_BANNER configuration. (BTW, this solution didn't work for me anyways).

Comment: I didn't try it, but I think you can use `updateViewLayout(View, LayoutParam)` to update the layout of your gameView with a computed value for the bottom margin.
Doc link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#updateViewLayout%28android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams%29

Comment: I have solved the issue differently. See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I coped with the same problem. The idea is first to set the `AdView` and then put the `gameView` below the `AdView` in the layout.

```
@Override public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Create the layout
    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

    // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    // Create the libgdx View
    View gameView = initializeForView(new HelloWorld(), false);

    // Create and setup the AdMob view
    AdView adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "xxxxxxxx"); // Put in your secret key here
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

    // Add the AdMob view
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
    adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

    //define in resource xml: <item type="id" name="adViewId"/>
    adView.setId(R.id.adViewId); 

    layout.addView(adView, adParams);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams gameParams = 
        new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    gameParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, adView.getId());

    // Add the libgdx view
    layout.addView(gameView, gameParams);

    // Hook it all up
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

Comment: This line "initializeForView(new HelloWorld(), false);" seems to have changed.

Comment: Got it. I forgot line: "adView.setId(R.id.adViewId); ". Excellent. Thx!

Comment: http://www.badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=19036
Says this isn't good. Could interfere with OpenGL...?

Comment: Might be, although I didn't have any issues with that.

Comment: It seemed to work for me as well. Though the main problem with your (really nicer approach) is of course that it might be difficult to achieve the same on ios (I don't know much about ios)..

Comment: Yes, this is a platform dependent implementation, you are right about that.